# Sum columns by group (row names) in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sum, aggregate

Let's say I have a matrix called `x`.

```
x <- structure(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
.Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Cake", "Pie", "Cake", "Pie", "Pie"),
c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs"))) 

x
     Mon   Tue   Wed   Thurs
Cake   1     0     1      1
Pie    0     0     1      1
Cake   1     1     0      1
Pie    0     0     1      1
Pie    0     0     1      1
```

I want to sum each column grouped by row names:

```
     Mon   Tue   Wed   Thurs
Cake   2     1     1      2
Pie    0     0     3      3
```

I've tried using `addmargins(x)`, but that just gives me the sum of each column and row. Any suggestions? I searched other questions, but couldn't figure this out.

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: structure(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("Cake", "Pie", 
"Cake", "Pie", "Pie"), c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs")))

Comment: thanks! you can obtain df below with `transform(data.frame(m), Name=rownames(m))` where `m` is your table.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel he can keep it a matrix. It's even better. Modified my solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a vectorized base solution

```
rowsum(df, row.names(x))
#      Mon Tue Wed Thurs
# Cake   2   1   1     2
# Pie    0   0   3     3
```

Or `data.table` version using `keep.rownames = TRUE` in order to convert your row names to a column

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = rn]
#      rn Mon Tue Wed Thurs
# 1: Cake   2   1   1     2
# 2:  Pie   0   0   3     3
```

Comment: No, you can do `setDT(df)[,as.list(colSums(.SD)),Name]`. But `colSums` isn't efficient in this case because it will convert the whole thing to a matrix. `lapply(.SD, sum)` is the way to go.

Comment: Oh perfect! Did not know rowsum as well, very neat base R solution!

Comment: Though I wonder what type of data OP actually has. I'm starting to suspect its a matrix.

Comment: Yes, reason of the `dput`, because duplicated rownames seemed weird to me for a `df` ...

Comment: That's even better though for `rowsum` as it has a special method for matrices.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this

```
df <- read.table(head=TRUE, text="
Name       Mon   Tue   Wed   Thurs
Cake   1     0     1      1
Pie    0     0     1      1
Cake   1     1     0      1
Pie    0     0     1      1
Pie    0     0     1      1")

aggregate(. ~ Name, data=df, FUN=sum)
##   Name Mon Tue Wed Thurs
## 1 Cake   2   1   1     2
## 2  Pie   0   0   3     3
```

also with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, Name) %>%
    summarise(Mon = sum(Mon), Tue = sum(Tue), Wed = sum(Wed), Thurs = sum(Thurs))
```

or better

```
 group_by(df, Name) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Comment: How do I add in the "Name" column?

Comment: assuming  your data contains `rownames`, maybe you can try `df$Name <- rownames(df)`

Comment: This is *not* how you would do this with `dplyr`

Comment: There’s `summarise_each` (sic), which is better in this case. But you’d need to add the names column first via `add_rownames('Name')`.

Comment: `library(dplyr)
group_by(df, Name) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), Mon:Thurs)`

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `plyr`:

```
ldply(split(df, df$Name), function(u) colSums(u[-1]))
#   .id Mon Tue Wed Thurs
#1 Cake   2   1   1     2
#2  Pie   0   0   3     3
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Cake", 
"Pie"), class = "factor"), Mon = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Tue = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Wed = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Thurs = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Name", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thurs"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```