# Count 1s in binary variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks something like this

```
Colour Q1 Q2 Q3
yellow  1  0  1 
green   0  0  1
red     1  1  1
black   0  1  0
green   1  0  1
white   0  0  1
yellow  1  1  1
```

and I'd like a table that looks like this so I can plot some bar charts in ggplot2 where the x-axis would have 3 quarters and each quarter would have the counts of each colour. I tried `table()` (and others that have been suggested here), but it gave me `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which only makes it harder since I don't know how to deal with that in order to plot bar graph using `ggplot2`.

```
Colour Q1 Q2 Q3
yellow  2  1  2
red     1  1  1
green   1  0  2
white   0  0  1
black   0  1  0
```

Comment: You question has two unrelated parts: do you want to count variables or plot using `ggplot2`?

Comment: @PoGibas  I want to count.

Comment: You can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090119/summing-all-columns-by-group
Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462651/sum-columns-by-group-in-a-matrix

Comment: I downvoted because this question consists of 2 questions that have EACH been answered numerous times here on SO. Lack of effort.

Comment: @PoGibas oh wow. I wasn't thinking about summing at all. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreElrico, I also expected to find tons of duplicates of this question on SO. To my surprise, I was not able to find an *exact* duplicate. Perhaps, some one else has a good duplicate for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have searched SO but I have not found an *exact* duplicate of this question.

The OP has requested:

> ... so I can plot some bar charts in ggplot2 where the x-axis would have 3 quarters and each quarter would have the counts of each colour.

For this, aggregation is not the crucial point here (`ggplot2` has functions to deal with different statistics) but *reshaping* the data in order to form an x-axis: The separate columns `Q1`, `Q2`, and `Q3` need to be turned into one column of quarterly data with an additional `Quarter` column which will become the x-axis.

For reshaping from wide to long format we can use

```
long <- tidyr::gather(raw_data, "Quarter", "Count", -Colour)
```

or

```
long <- data.table::melt(raw_data, "Colour", , "Quarter", "Count")
```

(just to mention a few options).

Both return a new dataset in long format:

```
long
```

> ```
>    Colour Quarter Count
> 1  yellow      Q1     1
> 2   green      Q1     0
> 3     red      Q1     1
> 4   black      Q1     0
> 5   green      Q1     1
> 6   white      Q1     0
> 7  yellow      Q1     1
> 8  yellow      Q2     0
> 9   green      Q2     0
> 10    red      Q2     1
> 11  black      Q2     1
> 12  green      Q2     0
> 13  white      Q2     0
> 14 yellow      Q2     1
> 15 yellow      Q3     1
> 16  green      Q3     1
> 17    red      Q3     1
> 18  black      Q3     0
> 19  green      Q3     1
> 20  white      Q3     1
> 21 yellow      Q3     1
> ```

Now, we can tell `ggplot()`

- where to place the bars along the x-axis (`Quarter`),
- which colour to use for filling the bars (`Colour`),
- and the height of the bars (`Count`).

by

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long) + 
  aes(Quarter, Count, fill = Colour) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

#### Data

```
raw_data <- data.table::fread("
Colour Q1 Q2 Q3
yellow  1  0  1 
green   0  0  1
red     1  1  1
black   0  1  0
green   1  0  1
white   0  0  1
yellow  1  1  1")
```