# R counting rows that meet criteria for all possible column pairs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, matching

I have a data frame `df`.

```
ID  001-alpha   001-sigma   001-delta   001-gamma   002-alpha   002-beta    002-charlie 002-delta
12  1           2           3           3           2               NA          2               0
21  NA          1           3           NA          3               2           2               NA
24  1           2           NA          3           3               1           3               2
36  NA          2           3           4           2               2           NA              1
44  NA          1           2           3           1               2           1               2
57  0           NA          2           3           1               1           3               1
```

In this `df`, I have several columns:

1. `ID` field represents the product ID, which is unique
2. Column names that begin with `001-` or `002-` represent some specifications for those products

##### Requirement

I am interested in checking for each pair of product specifications, how many IDs are common i.e., they contain non-null or non `NA` values.

To explain further, if I take the **first two columns** (`001-alpha` and `001-sigma`) as an example. Here, ID = 12 and ID = 24 is common or non-null between these columns. For the remaining IDs, there are missing values in one of the columns. So my required output column `001-alpha-sigma` will have a value `2`.

Similarly, for the **first** and the **third** columns (`001-alpha` and `001-delta`), again there are only two common IDs (i.e., ID = 12 and ID = 57) that contain non-null values across these two columns. So the output column `001-alpha-delta` will contain `2`.

My required output is as below:

```
001-alpha-sigma 001-alpha-delta 001-alpha-gamma 001-sigma-delta 001-sigma-gamma 001-delta-gamma 002-alpha-beta  002-alpha-charlie   002-alpha-delta 002-beta-charlie    002-beta-delta  002-charlie-delta
2               2               3               4               4               4               5               5                   5               4                   4               4
```

Is there are an easy approach to extract this information? e.g., can we use dplyr for this?

I have looked at a few other posts but they do not meet my requirement. For example,

[Sum columns by group (row names) in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462651/sum-columns-by-group-row-names-in-a-matrix)

For convenience, I am also sharing `dput(df)` below.

```
structure(list
(ID = structure(1:6, .Label = c("12", "21", "24", "36", "44", "57"), 
class = "factor"), 
`001.alpha` = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 0L), 
`001.sigma` = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA), 
`001.delta` = c(3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
`001.gamma` = c(3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), 
`002.alpha` = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
`002.beta` = c(NA,2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
`002.charlie` = c(2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L,3L), 
`002.delta` = c(0L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you to your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question involves some simple tidy-select work based on all pairs of the two column names. I begin by make a ones and twos subset of the dataframe. Then in the main function, I start by creating a dataframe of all of the possible combinations of two names from the input. I mutate to create a column of the original data selected to have only the two columns of the specified row, then drop_na and count the rows of each subset data frame. The procedure is finished with some name manipulation and pivoting.

Let me know if this works:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:6, .Label = c("12", "21", "24", "36", "44", "57"), 
class = "factor"), 
`001.a.alpha` = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 0L), `001.b.sigma` = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA), `001.c.delta` = c(3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L), `001.e.gamma` = c(3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), `002.ff.alpha` = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), `002.ef.beta` = c(NA,2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), `002.gh.charlie` = c(2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L,3L), `002.vv.delta` = c(0L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame") %>%
  as_tibble()

ones <- select(df, contains("001"))
twos <- select(df, contains("002"))

main <- function(tib, df) {
  t(combn(colnames(tib), 2)) %>%
    as_tibble(.name_repair = ~c("first_var", "second_var")) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(contains_both = list(select(df, all_of(c(first_var, second_var)))),
           result = nrow(drop_na(contains_both)),
           combined_name = (str_c(str_extract(first_var, "^\\d+"),
                                  str_extract(first_var, "[:alpha:]+$"),
                                  str_extract(second_var, "[:alpha:]+$"),
                                  sep = "-"))) %>%
    select(combined_name, result) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = combined_name, values_from = result)
}
bind_cols(
  main(ones, df),
  main(twos, df))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting a solution. Could you please explain it a little bit so that I may tweak it for my actual data set?

Comment: Sure, let me know if that works for you. I changed up the code to match your expected output exactly as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, the previous code seems to work on the example data set.
I am not trying it on my original data set.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Is there anything else I can do for you? Will you accept my answer?

Comment: Could you kindly explain only this function that you wrote initially:
```
main <- function(tib, df_NM) {
  t(combn(colnames(tib), 2)) %>%
    as_tibble(.name_repair = ~c("first_var", "second_var")) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(contains_both = list(select(df_NM, all_of(c(first_var, second_var)))),
           result = nrow(drop_na(contains_both))) %>%
    select(-contains_both)
}```

Comment: You can try writing a return( before the initial t(, and closing it before every pipe then rerunning the function. We take a combination of all the variable names of the input in sets of two, transpose it to a tibble, then do some rowwise restructuring of the entire data set to finally count the rows we need with drop_na.